# import mysql database exported with phpmyadmin into local lamp stack

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I exported mydb.sql from phpMyAdmin. It is about 0.9GB in size.

I copied mydb.sql onto an external hard drive, plugged that drive into another computer on which I just installed a LAMP stack.

On that new computer, in Ubuntu 14.04, from terminal, I type

mysql -u -p, and log into mysql.

Then I type

```
mysql> use mydb
mysql> source mydb.sql
```

Boom! It takes off. But within five minutes, failure:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in <b' at line 83
```

It appears from lots of google searches that this has to do with my php.ini file and its max_execution_time and other limits. I have changed that file to up those limits, but I still get the same error.

Any ideas? I thought that bringing `mydb.sql` in via the mysql command line would not involve php, but apparently it does.

Comment: In command line there is no max_execution, only in web servers, I think the backup didn't finish correctly, can you check the last lines of that file: mydb.sql?, you can use tail for that.

Comment: No, this is not a PHP error. This is an **SQL** error - some text you were inserting caused a syntax error. The fact that the text happens to be a php error message is irrelevant - your sql is bad.

Comment: @Marc B, thanks I wondered about that. Could it be something phpMyAdmin put in when I exported?

Comment: Save your sql file into your root folder, let's say /var/www/htdocs/ then run this, change the credentials of course.  mysql -u <mysql username> -p <mysql database name> /var/www/htdocs/sql_import.sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'<br /><b>Fatal error</b>:  Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in <b' at line 83
```

This line should not be in your mydb.sql. This question has been tagged phpmyadmin so it's easy to guess that the data was exported with it but the script was terminated when it reached 300 seconds which is the max allowed on your server.

You have two options:

1) change your php.ini to increase the max execution time

2) dump the database using mysqldump

Comment: yes, dumping with mysqldump seems the right option. Just figuring out how to do THAT... I'm running xampp and it's proving extremely difficult to interact with mysql via command line.  Note to self -- never use xampp, always manually install LAMP!

Comment: to be clear, I exported mydb.sql from phpMyAdmin, tried the import via mysql command line on the other computer.

Comment: Well ther you are! it confirms that it's the php.ini setting that limits execution time on your webserver that's to blame.

Comment: so the php.ini on the server from which I exported needs to be edited to up the execution time, and then re-export from phpMyAdmin? It seems odd that a php time constraint on one machine would cause a failure on another machine on which the server is not involved in importing the db.

Comment: It's not odd: the PHP time constraint on the exporting machine generated some malformed SQL inside your file.

Comment: As marc has pointed out it's not odd at all. Really all you need to do is to look at the tail end of your dump.sql file to confirm all these for yourself.