# Error import mysql database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i export my database and export to another computer use phpmyadmin

but it error,

Static analysis:

2 errors were found during analysis.

Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 53)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "div" at position 1)
SQL query:

```
<div class="error"><h1>Error</h1><p><strong>SQL query:</strong> <a href="db_sql.php?sql_query=SET+time_zone+%3D+%22%2B00%3A00%22&amp;show_query=1&amp;db=project1&amp;token=9e474724fcd1b27aa482f098f19b22f1"><span class="nowrap"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Edit" alt="Edit" class="icon ic_b_edit" />&nbsp
```

MySQL said: Documentation #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near `<div class="error"><h1>Error</h1><p><strong>SQL query:</strong> <a href="db_sql.` at line 1

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '<div class="error"><h1>Error</h1><p><strong>SQL query:</strong>
<a href="db_sql.' at line 1

Comment: So what is your question here? You got a clear error message stating the issues.

Comment: How big is your database? What export file type did you use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [import mysql database from external drive into local lamp stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995040/import-mysql-database-from-external-drive-into-local-lamp-stack)

Comment: @e4c5 No this is not a duplicate - different error message altogether (maximum execution time exceeded).

Comment: Did you ever resolve this error? I suddenly have exactly the same problem. I moved to a new host with a new MySQL server and now suddenly when I try to import a .SQL file into my local server (after exporting successfully from the web server) I get this same message.

Answer (score 2):

I hade the same error, and I noticed that mysql didn't export all tables database; still can't figure the reason, but I started to exporting and importing the tables as groups

[image]

After exporting the tables, you can import them, without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your export file clearly contains HTML code and not SQL code. Make sure you export your database properly. You can export your database in phpMyAdmin as follows.

> 1. Log into phpMyAdmin
> 2. Click the database you are working with in the left menu
> 3. Click Export in the top menu
> 4. Under the Export heading, ensure that all of your tables are selected and that the SQL option is selected.
> 5. Ensure the Save as file option (towards bottom of page) is checked.
> 6. Click Go
> 7. You will be prompted to either open or save the file. Please select the option to save the file.

-- cited from http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/phpmyadmin/export-database-using-phpmyadmin

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13379360)

Comment: Edited my answer. I hope it now contains the essential parts of the answer.

Comment: I don't think the problem is that it as an HTML file. I exported as a SQL file and on import I receive exactly the same error message reported by the OP as well.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem even after downloading in the sql form. My problem was with wp_comments table I exported all the other tables and for  wp_comments table I just downloaded the structure only then manually inserted the values. My problem got solved

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I want to migrate my wordpress to a new doamin, so I tried many options;
the best one that fixes my problem is trying exporting/importing database using the command line in the terminal.

Export DB: `mysqldump -u usernameDB -p name_DB > /home/file.sql`
Importing DB: `mysql -u username_newDB -p name_newDB < /home/file.sql`

NOTICE ALL COMMAND ARE EXECUTED IN TERMINAL not logged in Mysql DB.

Answer (score -1):

The SQL file you want to import is not a proper correct file, there maybe some issue in yourdb.sql file. Open that file in notepad and take a look.