# Count a data table and sum it and fill an empty data with default value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table that only contains date data, and I want to count the number of times that data is in the same month, and for that problem it's finished, and now I get a new problem that is the missing month, this is because there is no data on the month that. And now I want to add the empty month with default value 0 even though the month is not in the table. Can anyone help me based on my query?

this my data

```
start_date  |end_date
------------------------
 2018-10-01 |2018-10-02
 2018-01-04 |2018-02-04
 2018-08-01 |2018-10-01
```

this my query

```
    select month(month_table) as month_table
         , sum(cstart) as cstart 
         , sum(cend) as cend 
      from 
         (
          (select `start_date` as month_table
                , 1 as cstart
                , 0 as cend 
             from newdata
          ) 
  union all 
          ( select `end_date`
                 , 0
                 , 1 
              from newdata 
           ) 
          ) dd 
      group 
         by monthname(month_table)
          , month(month_table) 
      order 
         by month(month_table)
```

and the results is

```
month_table|cstart|cend
      1      |  1   |  0
      2      |  0   |  1
      8      |  1   |  0
      10     |  1   |  2
```

and i want to add new query so my results will be

```
 month_table|cstart|cend
      1      |  1   |  0
      2      |  0   |  1
      3      |  0   |  0
      4      |  0   |  0
      5      |  0   |  0
      6      |  0   |  0
      7      |  0   |  0
      8      |  1   |  0
      9      |  0   |  0
      10     |  1   |  2
      11     |  0   |  0
      12     |  0   |  0
```

this my fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c18b5f/3/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a table with all months. You can create one ad hoc with a subquery using `UNION ALL`. Then left join the count subqueries to that table.

```
SELECT m.month month_table,
       coalesce(s.count, 0) cstart,
       coalesce(e.count, 0) cend
       FROM (SELECT 1 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 2 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 3 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 4 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 5 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 6 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 7 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 8 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 9 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 10 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 11 month
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 12 month) m
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT month(n.start_date) month,
                              count(*) count
                              FROM newdata n
                              GROUP BY month(n.start_date)) s
                      ON s.month = m.month
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT month(n.end_date) month,
                              count(*) count
                              FROM newdata n
                              GROUP BY month(n.end_date)) e
                      ON e.month = m.month
       ORDER BY m.month;
```

Comment: thanks man for help my problem, you so awesome :) this query work aswell

Answer (score 0):

this should be the answer for this issue:

```
IF EXISTS(select * FROM sys.views where name = 'monthnotexict')
drop view monthnotexict
go
    create view monthnotexict as
        select 1 as month_table,0 as cstart ,0 as cend  from newdata union 
        select 2 as month_table,0 as cstart ,0 as cend from newdata union 
        select 3 as month_table,0 as cstart,0 as cend from newdata union 
        select  4 as month_table,0 as cstart,0 as cend from newdata union 
        select  5 as month_table,0 as cstart,0 as cend from newdata union 
        select  6 as month_table,0 as cstart,0 as cend from newdata union 
        select  7 as month_table,0 as cstart,0 as cend from newdata union 
        select  8 as month_table,0 as cstart,0 as cend  from newdata union 
        select  9 as month_table,0 as cstart,0 as cend from newdata union 
        select  10 as month_table,0 as cstart,0 as cend from newdata union 
        select  11 as month_table,0 as cstart,0 as cend from newdata union 
        select  12 as month_table,0 as cstart,0 as cend from newdata


    go
     SELECT DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month,M.month_table-1, CAST('2008-01-01' AS datetime)))as month_table
             , sum(cstart) as cstart 
             , sum(cend) as cend 
          from monthnotexict left join
             (
              (select 
                    , 1 as cstart
                    , 0 as cend 
                 from newdata

              ) 
      union all 
              ( 
                     , 0
                     , 1 
                  from newdata 

               ) 
    union all
    (
    select
    month_table
                 , sum(cstart) as cstart 
                 , sum(cend) as cend  
        from monthnotexict
group by month_table

    )


              ) dd on dd.cend=M.cend or dd.cstart=M.cstart

  group by M.month_table
```

as your request in comment I changed my code (now its without error and month number changed to month name)
I hope its done!

Comment: sorry but i so confuse, last time i'm tryng but got error, can u explain to me how can i use that query?

Comment: first I created view to get date which date is not exist in newdata then I union it in your code. what is the error you get?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '--=========

Comment: maybe you can help me, to change the number of months to the name of the month.

Comment: Static analysis: 1 errors were found during analysis. Unrecognized statement type. (near "IF EXISTS" at position 0). MySQL said: Documentation #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'drop view monthnotexict go create view monthnotexict as select 1 ' at line 2. im still confuse can you help me?

Comment: seems that you have  a problem in your php , my code works fine in sql server I didn't check it in php or mysql .may you can handle your problem here: [this is for php error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35826386/error-import-mysql-database)

Comment: im using mysql sir, default from xampp